# Datomic query: find all entities with some value

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

With this query:

```clj
{:find  [?e]
         :where [[?e :db/valueType :db.type/string]]}
```

I can find all entities with property named `:db/valueType` and value of `:db.type/string`. In my case with some data in the database it returns ten IDs.

How would I search for all entities with value of `:db.type/string`, regardless of the property name? For example this query:

```clj
{:find  [?e]
         :where [[?e _ :db.type/string]]}
```

returns an empty set. As far as I can understand Datomic's Datalog, `_` should work as a wildcard, matching anything, so the second query should at least return the same number of results as the first one, and maybe even more than that.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this example, the logical structure of the query is essentially correct, but the attribute ident keyword is not being resolved to its entity id. Note that this is a special case that occurs when you query with attributes as inputs - a scenario in which the query engine is not guaranteed to perform this conversion. See the Datomic docs on query (http://docs.datomic.com/query.html) for "Attributes as Query Inputs."

A way to restructure this query is as:

```
    (let [db (d/db conn)] 
            (d/q '[:find ?e 
                   :in $ ?id 
                   :where [?e _ ?id]] 
             db (d/entid db :db.type/string)))
```

In this case, we resolve the keyword :db.type/string to its entity id manually in the input to the parameterized query.

Comment: Thanks, it makes perfect sense: "types" are also entities. It's quite elegant, but sometimes one can forget it's entities all the way down! Accepting answer...